# How Can i Add the page views Dimension on google Big Query?

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm trying to add the page views Dimension (addition to the `total_users` and `total_sessions`) on Google Big Query per platform as you can see. Does someone know how?

```
SELECT
platform,
SUM(users) AS total_users,
 SUM(sessions) AS total_sessions,
 FROM (
 SELECT
  CASE
      WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(hits.appInfo.id,r'^example$') AND 
 hits.page.hostname IS NULL THEN "Android"
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(hits.appInfo.id,r'^com.example.app$')
  AND hits.page.hostname IS NULL THEN "iOS"
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(hits.page.hostname,r'^m\..*?example\.') THEN "Mobile"
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(hits.page.hostname,r'^\w{2,3}\..*?example\.') THEN 
 "Desktop"
   ELSE "unknown"
 END AS platform,
 count (DISTINCT fullVisitorId) AS users,
 fullvisitorid,
 COUNT(DISTINCT visitid) AS sessions,
 SUM(totals.screenviews) AS screenviews
 FROM
 TABLE_DATE_RANGE([example_table],TIMESTAMP('2018-01-01'),TIMESTAMP('2018-03- 
  31'))
  GROUP EACH BY
  fullvisitorid,
  platform,
  )
  GROUP BY
   platform
```

Comment: what do you mean whit page views dimension? do you want the same data split by pagepath? or you want the count(pageviews)?

Comment: I want the sum of all of the pageviews, sum(paageviews) same data split by pagepath?

Comment: Can you provide a better description of what you want to achieve? It is still not clear what the *page views Dimension* is in your context, maybe you can share documentation links or provide a better description of what this metric should include. Also, I have found [this other Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31043713/4482491) where page views are counted, maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need the sub-query in your case. 
Some other notes:

- `COUNT(DISTINCT)` is only an estimation in legacy SQL
- `COUNT(DISTINCT visitId)` is not counting anything useful - please see [my answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419771/total-sessions-in-bigquery-vs-google-analytics-reports/46977975#46977975)
- For pageviews I simply added sum of totals.pageviews. you could also count hits where `hits.type='PAGE'`, see [Export-Schema](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719)

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(hits.appInfo.id,r'^example$') AND hits.page.hostname IS NULL THEN "Android"
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(hits.appInfo.id,r'^com.example.app$') AND hits.page.hostname IS NULL THEN "iOS"
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(hits.page.hostname,r'^m\..*?example\.') THEN "Mobile"
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(hits.page.hostname,r'^\w{2,3}\..*?example\.') THEN "Desktop"
    ELSE "unknown"
  END AS platform,
  COUNT(DISTINCT fullVisitorId) AS usersEst, -- approximate value .. count(distinct) in legacy sql is only an estimation. In standard sql it would be the real deal.
  EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(fullVisitorId) as exactUsers,
  -- COUNT(DISTINCT visitid) AS sessions, -- that's wrong! visitIds are only unique per fullvisitorid
  SUM(totals.visits) as sessions,
  SUM(totals.screenviews) AS screenviews,
  SUM(totals.pageviews) AS pageviews
FROM
  TABLE_DATE_RANGE([example_table],TIMESTAMP('2018-01-01'),TIMESTAMP('2018-03-31'))
GROUP BY
  1
```

Please consider using standard SQL - it's more powerful and you get more control.